# .htaccess rewrite portion of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two requirements:

1. I want to rewrite `component/testcomp` in URL to just `comp`.

`https://www.website.com/component/testcomp` should look as:
`https://www.website.com/comp` in URL.

2. All requests coming fo `website.com` should be 301 redirected to `https://www.website.com`

Below is the content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
   IndexIgnore *

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]


RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I do so? I tried adding Rewrite Rule but it is not working. Let me know the Rewrite rule & where should I place it.

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite "/component/testcomp" to just "comp", *I think* you have to flag it with R, or use R=301 to make it a permanent. I have a feeling you may have to adjust additional rules, however.

```
RewriteRule ^component/testcomp/(.*)$ /comp/$1 [L,R]
```

or to make it permanent:

```
RewriteRule ^component/testcomp/(.*)$ /comp/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Added it at the last of .htaccess but it does not work. May you please let me know where should I place it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /component/test(comp)(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

and then,

```
RewriteRule ^comp(.*)$ /component/testcomp$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```